# canvas.getContext("2d") does not work

Tags: javascript, firefox, canvas

this is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            (function drawCanvas(){
                var canv = document.getElementById('testcanvas1');

                if(canv.getContext){
                    alert("test");
                    var context = doof.getContext('2d');

                    context.fillStyle = "rgb(255, 0, 255)";
                    context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                }
            })();
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="testcanvas1"></canvas>
    </body>
</html>
```

There is no alert, so I assume the Variable canv.getContext is false. Why? In general .getContext('2d') does not work for my firefox 34. How can I make this funktion work?

Comment: `canv` is `null` because `#testcanvas1` hasn't been loaded yet. Therefore, `canv.getContext` throws an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're executing your code before the document is loaded. Solution:

```
window.onload = function() {
    (function drawCanvas(){
        var canv = document.getElementById('testcanvas1');

        if(canv.getContext){
            alert("test");
            var context = doof.getContext('2d');

            context.fillStyle = "rgb(255, 0, 255)";
            context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        }
    })();
}
```